# Ajax Call removes UI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm having an issue when submitting form data to the server. The data is passed via AJAX to the server and in return the account, view-component is reloaded. This works as it's meant to but the Ui in the account view-component is missing the responsive Ui controls. Below is a demo of the issue I'm having.

[image]

The Responsive controls are still "working" when the page is resized past the mobile view-width and back the plus/minus icons are re-added but it's on the submission of the form, these Ui elements and the dropdown functionality is removed, making it impossible to view the hidden records in the dropdown on mobile. Below is what it looks like on desktop.

[image]

Below is the jquery for the AJAX Post and responsive layout.

AJAX Post

```
$('#AccountListContainer').on('submit', 'form' ,function (e) {
e.preventDefault()

var container = $("#AccountListContainer")
var dataToSend = $(this).serialize()

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: dataToSend,
    context: AccountListContainer,

    success: function (data) {
        displayMessage(data.result, data.message)  
        
        //$.get("/Bank/UpdateAccountList", function (data) { container.html(data) })
        $(container).load("/Bank/UpdateAccountList")

        console.log('Ajax post success')
    },

    error: function () {
        console.log('Throw Error')
        //throw Error page?
    }
    
})
});
```

Responsive layout

```
$(document).ready(responsiveTransactionTable)



function responsiveTransactionTable() {
    var isMobile = false
    var collapsibleHeadings = $('thead > tr').children().filter('.collapsible')

function toggleTableLayout() {
    var wWidth = $(window).width();

    //medium == 768
    if (wWidth >= 992) {
        console.log('You\'re in Desktop view')

        if (isMobile == true) {
            $('tr').unbind();
            $('.toggle-button').remove()
            $('.subData').remove()

            $('tr.data').removeClass('opened')
            isMobile = false
        }

    } else {
        console.log('You\'re in mobile view')
        
        //$('td:first-child').css('color','red')

        if (isMobile == false) {
            $('tr.data > td:first-child').prepend('<span style="padding:5px" class="fas fa-plus toggle-button "></span>')
            isMobile = true
        }

        $('tbody > tr').unbind('click').bind('click.', function (e) {

            var selectedRow = $(this)
            var toggleIcon = selectedRow.find('.fas')

            if (selectedRow.hasClass('opened')) {

                toggleIcon.removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
                selectedRow.next('tr').remove()
                selectedRow.toggleClass('opened')
            } else {
                toggleIcon.removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');

                var newRow = $('<tr>').addClass('subData')
                var cols = "";

                cols += "<td colspan='100%'>"
                cols += "<div style='dispaly:block'>"
                cols += "<table class='table'>"

                selectedRow.children().filter('.collapsible').each(function (index) {
                    cols += "<tr>"
                    cols += "<th>" + collapsibleHeadings.eq(index).text() + "</th>"
                    cols += "<td>" + $(this).text() + "</td>"
                    cols += "</tr>"
                })

                cols += "</table>"

                newRow.append(cols)
                newRow.insertAfter(selectedRow)

                selectedRow.toggleClass('opened')
            }
        })
    }
}

toggleTableLayout()
$(window).resize(toggleTableLayout)


$('#AccountListContainer').on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
    $(this).prev().find('.fas').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up')

}).on('hide.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
    $(this).prev().find('.fas').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down')
})
}
```

I've been scratching my head on why it's doing this for a while. Any answers or pointers would be greatly appreciated and I can provide more information if needed.

Q: How would I make it so that on AJAX post, it keeps the plus/minus icons and dropdown functionality when in mobile view?

Thank you

Sidenote: the Error in the demo Gif is supposed to happen when input == null + the records are dummy data

Comment: Sounds like you are replacing elements that had event listeners on them with new ones that don't. If so use event delegation

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah I'm replacing the #AccountListContainer on the page with an updated one from the server. I looked at Jquery's Delegate function and I'm not too sure how to apply it. I tried adding [ $(document).delegate("form", "submit", function () { responsiveTransactionTable() }); ] to the top of the responsive and nothing happens until i resize and shrink the width and I end up with two plus/minus icons

Comment: What do you do at the beginning for the UI controls to appear - before the ajax call? Do you maybe need to do that again, now that you have new content?

Comment: @PeterKA At the start, I do nothing the page loads I open one of the accordions select one of the controls e.g. "Delete" the AJAX call is made and the account list is updated minus the record that was deleted. I go to open another accordion, like in the first step now the plus/minus controls and dropdown functionality is broken until I resize and shrink the width. I've tried calling the responsiveAccountTable() function after AJAX post and I get the same result until I resize and shrink where I get a second plus/minus control icon.

Comment: @PeterKA the plus/minus icons and dropdown controls are active only when the screen is < 992px in width otherwise you get the full table view like in the second image

Comment: `delegate` is really old and deprecated. You want to use `$(document).on('submit', 'form', function...` or whatever other event(s) needed

Comment: @charlietfl I changed that line from delegate to on to the same effect. every time I call the ajax nothing happens until I resize and shrink the width I get an additional plus/minus icon for each call. It probably has something to do with the way I'm calling it however the heading functionality the up/down icons and functionality works fine it's just the responsive table that's having the issue

Comment: Needing a resize before events work is  weird issue. I've been helping debug on forums like this and the old jQuery forum for years and that's a bit of a new one on me. To be honest without access to a demo that reproduces the issue it's really hard to help more

Comment: @charlietfl I could put together a Codepen of the frontend including the javascript portion if that helps?

Comment: Sure , if you can come close to replicating it go for it

Comment: That I'm not sure I can do as it's wired up to the backend and I'll have to think of a way to simulate Ajax calling the refreshed UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution:

I called my ResponsiveTransactionTable() function as a second argument of jquerys .load()

```
$('#AccountListContainer').on('submit', 'form' ,function (e) {
e.preventDefault()

var container = $("#AccountListContainer")
var dataToSend = $(this).serialize()

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: dataToSend,
    context: AccountListContainer,

    success: function (data) {
        displayMessage(data.result, data.message)  
        
        //$.get("/Bank/UpdateAccountList", function (data) { container.html(data) })
        $(container).load("/Bank/UpdateAccountList", function () {
            responsiveTransactionTable()
        })
       

        console.log('Ajax post success')
    },

    error: function () {
        console.log('Throw Error')
        //throw Error page?
    }
    
})

});
```

The result:

[image]

Thank you @charlietfl for your replies